# Ошибка 404 на laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, route

нужно вывести список удаленных товаров, с возможностью восстановления отдельных. использую softDeletes.

Код deleted.blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('dryFeeds.restoran', $feed->id) }}">
    <div class='product_part'>
        <div class="product_part_img">
            <center>
                <img src = '{{asset ($feed->photo)}}' alt="Product_photo">
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class='product_part_title'>
            {{$feed->title}} <br>
        </div>

        <div class='product_part_cart'>
            <img src="{{ asset('img/icons/cart.png') }}">
            <div class="product_part_price">
                {{$feed->price}} ₽
            </div> 
        </div><br>
        <center>Восстановить</center>
    </div>
</a>
```

Код web.php

```
Route::get('/dryFeeds/deleted', [DryFeedsController::class, 'deleted']) -> name('dryFeeds.deleted');
Route::get('/dryFeeds/restore/{product}', [DryFeedsController::class, 'restore']) -> name('dryFeeds.restore');
```

Код DryFeedsController.php

```
public function restore(product $product){         
    dd($product[id]);                                                                           
}
```

В итоге выходит окно с ошибкой 404
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил засунув blade для восстановления в отдельную папку, теперь они не в dryFeeds, а в deletedDryFeeds, теперь все роуты видны